# LinQ query that counts the number of elements in a list of objects in another list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have this kind of structure :

At first, there is a list of families.

EDIT: each family contains a group of person

EDIT: each person is defined by a gender

I have to count how many of those persons are males, and how many are females, so here is what I tried:

```
int boys = ListOfFams.Where(f => f.persons.Where(p => p.gender == gender.male)).Count();
```

It seems I cannot just ask for the number of males or females because I need a condition to put after the first "where", but then, I don't know how I should build my request.

Do you guys have any idea ?

Thank you for your time

Edit again: Thank you all for your answers, and sorry for the late edit on the question regarding the group of persons etc.

Comment: Did you try `int boys = ListOfFams.SelectMany(s=>s.persons).Count(p => p.gender == gender.male));`?

Comment: I just edited my question because I realized I wrote it wrong, sorry

Comment: What does it mean `I need a condition to put after the first "where"`? Do you want to select persons by condition then count it by gender?

Comment: I meant there was something missing between "male) " and the other ")"

Comment: Informative: https://heyguys.cc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you select each family, then return the count of males in it, you would get an enumerable of counts - e.g {0,1,0,3,2,1} - you can then simply Sum those counts

```
  ListOfFams.Select(f => f.persons.Where(p => p.gender == gender.male).Count()).Sum();

//to reject nulls

ListOfFams.
    Where(f => f != null && f.persons != null).
    Select(f => f.persons.
    Where(p => p != null && p.gender == gender.male).
    Count()).
    Sum();
```

Comment: It seems that this might work
Do you know if it'll raise an exception if a familly / a group / a person is equal to null ?

Comment: @RyanL yes of course it will throw if any of those are `null`.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to ignore those exceptions and continue the count then ? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use LINQ's [`Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count) and [`Sum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum) to achieve that:

```
int boy = ListOfFams.Sum(f => f.persons.Count(p => p.gender == gender.male));
```

This counts the male persons per family and sums up the results.

---

If you expect any of those collections to contain `null` values, you need to protect against that like this:

```
int boy = ListOfFams.Sum(f => f?.persons?.Count(p => p?.gender == gender.male) ?? 0);
```

Now this only counts persons that are not `null` and male, and only persons of families that are not `null` and whose `persons` list is not `null`.
If a family or a `persons` collection is `null`, they are counted as `0`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are also correct, but there is a third way.

Essentially, you're not interested in the families, but the people in those families. Rather than performing a nested count (once per family) which you then sum, you can also:

1. Convert the list of families into a list of the people in those families

```
IEnumerable<Person> allPeopleInTheseFamilies = ListOfFams.SelectMany(fam => fam.persons);
```

2. Count how many males there are in that list.

```
int totalMales = allPeopleInTheseFamilies.Count(person => person.gender == gender.male);
```

This can of course be chained as well:

```
int totalMales = ListOfFams
                     .SelectMany(fam => fam.persons)
                     .Count(person => person.gender == gender.male);
```

If you're worried about nullability, you can add in extra null checks (though I would generally advise to avoid having nulls in the list in the first place)

```
int totalMales = ListOfFams
                     .Where(fam => fam != null && fam.persons != null)
                     .SelectMany(fam => fam.persons)
                     .Count(person => person != null && person.gender == gender.male);
```